# How to POST request multiple times in the same session using rvest and httr?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I am trying to scrape Turkish Fund Market data from https://www.tefas.gov.tr/TarihselVeriler.aspx . However, the data does not reside in HTML tags so I am posting a request with a form to get the data on the page.

I can successfully get data from the first page with correct parameters, however, **I cant traverse through pages and get data from the next pages** even after adding

```r
'ctl00$MainContent$ScriptManager1'='ctl00$MainContent$UpdatePanel1|ctl00$MainContent$ImageButtonGenelNext'
```

to the second post request form. I am not sure about the root cause but I was suspecting that every time I send a post request, instead of sending the request from the same session, it treats the request as it is from the new session. So in order to fix that, I have set cookies for post request using the data from
`tefas_session` but still, it did not work. You can check that two post requests return the same data by `price_table1$FonKodu==price_table2$FonKodu`. I was expecting that price_table1 would bring data from the first page and price_table2 would bring data from the second page.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(httr)

url<-"https://www.tefas.gov.tr/TarihselVeriler.aspx"

tefas_session<-html_session(
    url,
    httr::user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36")
)

tefas_form<-tefas_session %>%
    html_form()

fields<-tefas_form[[1]]$fields

#Arguments

fund_type<-'YAT' #Optional, default is 'YAT' which brings investment funds

fundId<-'' #Optional, default is empty string


TextBoxStartDate<-"15.01.2021"
TextBoxEndDate<-"30.01.2021"




first_page<-rvest:::request_POST(
    x = tefas_session,
    url = url,
    httr::user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36"),
    body=list(
        #these 4 values contain session data
        '__VIEWSTATE'=fields$'__VIEWSTATE'$value,
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'=fields$'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'$value,
        '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED'=fields$'__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED'$value,
        '__EVENTVALIDATION'=fields$'__EVENTVALIDATION'$value,
        
        #this fields selects the type of a fund.
        #'YAT' fetches investment funds, 'EMK' fetches retirement funds
        'ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonListFundMainType'=fund_type,
        
        #These are supposed to be empty
        'ctl00$MainContent$TextBoxOtherFund'='',
        'ctl00$MainContent$TextBoxWatermarkExtenderFund_ClientState'='',
        
        #this is optional. If left blank, it brings all funds. Else, it brings given fund
        'ctl00$MainContent$HiddenFieldFundId'=fundId,
        
        #See DropDownListExtraFundType
        'ctl00$MainContent$DropDownListExtraFundType'=DropDownListExtraFundType[[1]],
        
        #see DropDownListFundTypeExplanation
        'ctl00$MainContent$DropDownListFundTypeExplanation'=DropDownListFundTypeExplanation[[1]],
        
        #start date for data, minimum date
        'ctl00$MainContent$TextBoxStartDate'=TextBoxStartDate,
        
        'ctl00$MainContent$TextBoxWatermarkExtenderStartDate_ClientState'='',
        
        #last date for data, maximum date
        'ctl00$MainContent$TextBoxEndDate'=TextBoxEndDate,
        
        'ctl00$MainContent$ButtonSearchDates'='Görüntüle',
        
        'ctl00$MainContent$ScriptManager1'='ctl00$MainContent$UpdatePanel1|ctl00$MainContent$ButtonSearchDates'
    ),
    encode="form",
    set_cookies('ASP.NET_SessionId'=session_cookies$value[1],
                'TS01ec1a88'=session_cookies$value[2],
                'TS392566ef027'=session_cookies$value[3]))




price_table1<-read_html(first_page) %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="MainContent_GridViewGenel"]') %>%
    html_table() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    mutate(
        across(
            where(is.character),
            function(x) { gsub(pattern = ",",replacement = ".",x = x) })
    )



#To-Do
# Find a way to traverse through pages.

next_page<-'ctl00$MainContent$UpdatePanel1|ctl00$MainContent$ImageButtonGenelNext'

second_page<-rvest:::request_POST(
    x = tefas_session,
    url = url,
    httr::user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36"),
    body=list(
        #TO-DO: ENTER ALL FORM VALUES
        #these 4 values are used for cookies
        '__VIEWSTATE'=fields$'__VIEWSTATE'$value,
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'=fields$'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'$value,
        '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED'=fields$'__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED'$value,
        '__EVENTVALIDATION'=fields$'__EVENTVALIDATION'$value,
        
        '__EVENTTARGET'=next_page,
        
        #this fields selects the type of a fund.
        #'YAT' fetches investment funds, 'EMK' fetches retirement funds
        'ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonListFundMainType'=fund_type,
        
        #These are supposed to be empty
        'ctl00$MainContent$TextBoxOtherFund'='',
        'ctl00$MainContent$TextBoxWatermarkExtenderFund_ClientState'='',
        
        #this is optional. If left blank, it brings all funds. Else, it brings given fund
        'ctl00$MainContent$HiddenFieldFundId'=fundId,
        
        #See DropDownListExtraFundType
        'ctl00$MainContent$DropDownListExtraFundType'=DropDownListExtraFundType[[1]],
        
        #see DropDownListFundTypeExplanation
        'ctl00$MainContent$DropDownListFundTypeExplanation'=DropDownListFundTypeExplanation[[1]],
        
        #start date for data, minimum date
        'ctl00$MainContent$TextBoxStartDate'=TextBoxStartDate,
        
        'ctl00$MainContent$TextBoxWatermarkExtenderStartDate_ClientState'='',
        
        #last date for data, maximum date
        'ctl00$MainContent$TextBoxEndDate'=TextBoxEndDate,
        
        'ctl00$MainContent$ButtonSearchDates'='Görüntüle',
        
        'ctl00$MainContent$ScriptManager1'='ctl00$MainContent$UpdatePanel1|ctl00$MainContent$ImageButtonGenelNext'
    ),
    encode='form',
    set_cookies('ASP.NET_SessionId'=session_cookies$value[1],
                'TS01ec1a88'=session_cookies$value[2],
                'TS392566ef027'=session_cookies$value[3]))

price_table2<-read_html(second_page) %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="MainContent_GridViewGenel"]') %>%
    html_table() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    mutate(
        across(
            where(is.character),
            function(x) { gsub(pattern = ",",replacement = ".",x = x) })
    )


price_table1$FonKodu==price_table2$FonKodu
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand the question correctly, but the solution could be `RSelenium` with `rvest`.

Below a simple example about how to get the information from the tables of Genel Bilger section.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
driver <- rsDriver(browser= 'firefox', port = 4532L)
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]] 
remote_driver$navigate("https://www.tefas.gov.tr/TarihselVeriler.aspx")

empty_df<-list()
for(i in 1:100){ #I don't know how many pages has the site
#we check if there is the bottom next
tryCatch(expr = { #this to manage the error
  html_page<-remote_driver$getPageSource() %>% unlist() %>% read_html() %>% html_table( fill=TRUE) #this to get the table
  next_bottom<-remote_driver$findElement(using = 'xpath',value ='//*[@id="MainContent_ImageButtonGenelNext"]')$clickElement() #this to go next
  Sys.sleep(3)
  empty_df[[i]] <-(html_page[[4]]) #this to save the table that we got

  },
  error = function(e){          # Specifying error message
           message("There was an error message.")}) #this to know when we have the error
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! This works but doesn't actually solve my problem. I want the scraper to run without any browser (so without using Rselenium) . So is there any solution without using Rselenium and implementing rvest or httr?

Comment: I don't believe that is possible to switch pages without Selenium.